# How to prevent javascript code in text area from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I prevent user content which contains executable javascript from running when other users view my pages?

For example, if someone added this to a textbox on a page and then saved the form, how would I stop this from being executed when this content is viewed again?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.alert("hiiii!")
</script>
```

Comment: You need to Encode it before rendering back to browser.

Comment: That's not true. If you just enter Javascript code in a text area it will not execute. Where is your code?

Comment: And what are your efforts so far?

Comment: You should elaborate in your question about your whole scenario.  As someone has pointed out, JavaScript code entered into a `textarea` by itself will not execute.  What else are you doing with it?  Is it executing from the `textarea`?  Are you saving the code on the server-side and then rendering it to the browser?  What's executing it?

Comment: I have a text area when anyone put script like this its execute<script type="text/javascript">
window.alert("hiiii!")
</script>

Comment: @AtiqUrRehman: I disagree.  I'm unable to reproduce the described issue: http://jsfiddle.net/tCU9L/  A `textarea` by itself doesn't execute JavaScript code.  You must be doing _something_ with the content of that `textarea`, but you aren't telling us what.

Answer (score 1):

its called the xss you also need to check the [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) also check the [How to Avoid Cross-site scripting Vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)